# Elemento JSX não carrega usando this.state.list.map

Tags: javascript, react

Estou fazendo um forms em `React` e preciso que após o envio do formulário o mesmo seja renderizado em uma `div` diferente mostrando o conteúdo para o usuário Porem o componente `Showforms` não é renderizado e muito menos reconhecido, no terminal não me aparece nenhum erro se quer, e todos os componentes estão sendo devidamente chamados.

Segue a seguir o trecho do código.

```
state = {
    name: '',
    tel: '',
    email: '',
    description: '',
    formList: [],
}
```

**Função quando o botão de enviar é clicado**

```
saveForm = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const { state: { name, tel, email, description,formList } } = this
    const regex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
    const emailValidation = regex.test(email)

    if ((name === '') || ((tel === '') && (tel.length < 9)) || (email === '') || (description === '')) {
        alert('Preencha todos os campos devidamente')
    } else if (!emailValidation) {
        alert('Email inválido, preencha corretamente')
    } else {
        formList.push(name, tel, email, description)
        console.log(this.state.formList)
        alert('Seu formulário foi enviado com sucesso! Nós agradeçemos seu contato!')
    }
}
```

**Chamada do componentes para ser renderizado no DOM**

```
{/*list's information */}
<div id='descriptionConteiner'>
    {this.state.formList.map((list,index)=>{
        return <ShowForm key={`${list}-${index}`} list={list} index={index}/>
    })}
</div>
```

**O componente ShowForm é a seguinte:**

```
import React from 'react'


const ShowForm = props => {
    return <div>{props.list}</div>  
}
export default ShowForm
```

**O console.log(this.state.formList) é:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O resumo dos componentes é : (de acordo o componente "ShowForms") nem sequer é achado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não está renderizando o que? o que tem dentro de `formList`? `return <div>{props.list}</div>` isso não renderizada nada!

Comment: @novic exatamente o conteúdo do formList não é passado para o componente através do map. eu não sei porque =(

Comment: o que tem dentro do `formList`?

Comment: o conteudo dentro do formlist, o formlist é um array que guarda os inputs dos status (name,email,tel, description) após o salvamento através da função formlist.push. O conteudo que tem dentro do formlist são simples strings

Comment: guardar valores? então demonstre na sua pergunta com um console.log? não estou vendo, não tem como! `console.log(this.state.formList)`?

Comment: @novic eu editei o post com o consolo.log(this.state.formList) apos o botão salvar ser clicado

Comment: ah entendi já o seu erro, você não alterou o estado você não pode fazer assim! entendeu.?

Comment: Conseguir @novic, mto obrigado pela sua ajuda!!!!!

Comment: Eu fiz o exemplo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em nenhum momento no seu código está sendo armazenado o ultimo estado das variável criada na pergunta.

**Pontos relevantes:**

- [this.setState](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) é o método responsável em mudar o estado de alguma variável ou variáveis do seu componente no layout escrito como classes, se for utilizar a nova é o [Hook React.useState](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).
- Não foi utilizado o comando acima para alterar o estado desse componente.

---

Exemplo:

```js
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>{props.value}</div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value:'',
      formList: []
    }
    this.add = this.add.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  add() {
    let {value, formList} = this.state;
    formList.push(value);
    value = '';
    this.setState({value, formList});
  }
  handleChange(e) {
    let state = this.state;
    state[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState(state);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <input 
            type="text" 
            name="value"
            value={this.state.value} 
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <button onClick={this.add}>Add</button>        
        </div>
        {this.state.formList.map((item, ix) => <div>{item}</div>)}
      </div>     
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```